# Make HTML reload JavaScript src

Tags: javascript, html

On Ubuntu, I am using chart.js to make a graph of the values of a pressure sensor on an HTML file. I have completed most of the project, but I have run into a problem that I cannot find an adequate answer for.

What happens is I read the values of the pressure sensor using an Arduino, write them to the serial monitor, and read the serial monitor with the pySerial library in python. Then the python writes the values of the pressure sensor to the JavaScript file, and I call `chart.update()` in a self-invoking function in JavaScript.

I have gotten all of that to work, but the values of the chart do not update because the HTML does not "see" that the .js file has been reloaded in the following script tag: `<script src = "file:///home/warren/Work/new_graph.js"></script>`. I assume I will be using Jquery/Ajax, but everything I have found only confuses me more. 
Code: (Please do not judge me, I'm new to coding)

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.8.0"></script>

<style>
body {
font-family: Helvetica Neue, Arial, sans-serif;
text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
   max-width: 800px;
   margin: 50px auto;
}

h1 {
   font-weight: 200;
   font-size: 3em;
   margin: 0 0 0.1em 0;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  margin: 0 0 50px;
  color: #999;
}

a {
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: block;
  color: #3e95cd;
}
</style>

<title>Test js</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<h1>Test js</h1>
<canvas id="myChart" width="1600" height="900"></canvas>
</div>
<script src="file:///home/warren/Work/new_graph.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var arduino = [0,2,1.91,10,2.10,2.06,1.77,2.19,1.83,2.04,2.00,1.97,1.96]
var seconds = [6, 5.5, 5, 4.5, 4, 3.5, 3, 2.5, 2, 1.5, 1, .5, 0]
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var gradientStroke = ctx.createLinearGradient(500, 0, 100, 0);
gradientStroke.addColorStop(0, "#11375e");
gradientStroke.addColorStop(1, "#ef4659");
var gradientFill = ctx.createLinearGradient(500, 0, 100, 0);
gradientFill.addColorStop(0, "rgba(17, 55, 94, 0.6)");
gradientFill.addColorStop(1, "rgba(239, 70, 89, 0.6)");

var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
// The type of chart we want to create
type: 'line',
data: {
    labels: seconds,
    datasets: [{
        label: 'My First dataset',
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        data: arduino,
        borderColor: gradientStroke,
        fill: true,
        backgroundColor: gradientFill,
    }]
},

// Configuration options go here
options: {
    animation: {
    duration: 0,
    },
    scales: {
    xAxes:[{
        scaleLabel: {
        display: true,
        labelString: 'Time (s)',
        fontSize: 18
        },
        }],
    yAxes:[{
        scaleLabel: {
        display: true,
        labelString: 'Pressure (psi)',
        fontSize: 18
        },
        display: true,
        ticks: {
        suggestedMin: 1.7,
        suggestedMax: 2.2
             },
          }]
         },
    legend: {
        display: false
    },
    tooltips: {
        callbacks: {
           label: function(tooltipItem) {
                  return tooltipItem.yLabel;
           }
        }
    }
}
});
var counter = 0;

(function updateChart(){
    counter += 1;
    chart.data.datasets[0].data = arduino,
    console.log("Updated " + counter + " times");
    chart.update();
    setTimeout(updateChart, 2000)
})()
```

I have not included the python or the Arduino, as they are independent of the problem. 
Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you actually need here, if I understand correctly, is to reload the page every X seconds.

You have several options for that:

**Option 1: Reload through Javascript**

Place the following code in your JS file:

```
// reload every 10 seconds (10,000ms)

window.setTimeout(function() { 
    location.reload();
}, 10000);
```

**Option 2: Use a meta tag in html**

Place this code under the `head` section of your html:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="10">
```

Comment: I have tried this, but as I want the graph to update quickly (< 1 sec) I have problems with the html reloading to quickly and not rendering the graph in time. Thank you tho :)

Comment: So it looks like what you need here is to use ajax calls to reload just the data part, not the entire js file. You'll have to modify the python script so it will generate a json file with just the data. Then you need to load that file using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, you can't reload the js with HTML, but there are two workarounds to this.

1. Reload the HTML page using `window.location.reload()`
2. Put the entire javascript into a single function, and call it when the page is loaded and when you want the javascript to reload

Answer (score 0):

Use a meta tag which fits into your title. You can find that st the head of your document.